# Load data to the Table view from Parsed XML

Tags: ios, xml, uitableview, parsing

Previously I had a doubt regarding the Parsing XML. Thanks for all for giving me help to clear that.

Now I need to load the data which i parsed from the XML in to a table view. can any one help me in that.

[What I need is to load the courses which a student enrolls. The xml file is created based on the login query.]

Answer (score 1):

To display data in UITableView you must set its delegate and datasource properties to an object that implements UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols. Look reference docs for details.

There's also [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html) sample on apple site.